# How to get remote system process list using WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, remote-server

I am trying to create a WCF service which take a remote system name as parameter and gets all the processes running on it.

If same system name is given to the service, its giving the details of services running on it. However if you give machine name which is not same where the service is hosted its throwing error.

Error I am getting:

```
System.ServiceModel.FaultException<System.ServiceModel.ExceptionDetail> was caught
  Message=The RPC server is unavailable. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BA)
  Source=mscorlib
  Action=http://schemas.microsoft.com/net/2005/12/windowscommunicationfoundation/dispatcher/fault
  StackTrace:
    Server stack trace: 
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ThrowIfFaultUnderstood(Message reply, MessageFault fault, String action, MessageVersion version, FaultConverter faultConverter)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
    Exception rethrown at [0]: 
       at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
       at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
       at ServiceReference1.IService1.GetData(String serverName)
       at ServiceReference1.Service1Client.GetData(String serverName) in c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\website1\a721c869\c5802e85\App_WebReferences.nbhpvo6i.0.cs:line 53
       at _Default.Button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Users\xxxxx\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\WebSite1\Default.aspx.cs:line 70
  InnerException:
```

Answer (score 0):

Server with your web service deployed as well as target server should have Remote Procedure Call, Server and Remote Registry windows services running.

Check also that ports 9132, 9133 and 9134 are not blocked by firewall.